# I Created RSS FEED in php and the feed also showing on the page but they are now fatching by comment love boards, How can i fix it?

Tags: php, xml, rss, comments, feed

In this code feeds are showing when i am commenting `$description=$row['description'];` this section but not fetching by comment love boards please help
http://ravisah.in/feed
Here is my code please help

```
<?php
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $password = 'Qwaszx12';
        $dbname = 'ravisah';
        $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('error');

    @header("Content-type: text/rss+xml");

    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
            <rss version='2.0'>
            <channel>
            <title>Freelance Web Designer in Delhi, India - Ravi Sah</title>
            <link>http://www.ravisah.in</link>
            <description>I am Delhi based responsive website designer and website developer. I am passionate about designing and worked with various clients</description>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $title=$row['title'];
        $link=$row['slug_url'];
        $description=$row['description'];

        echo "<item>
                <title>$title</title>
                <link>http://ravisah.in/blog/$link</link>
                <description>$description</description>
             </item>";
    }
    echo "</channel>";
    echo "</rss>";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

RSS feed used to simple post any data in XML format. In above code "Love board" is not mentioned. You have fetch query from database using like operator.

You have change database query such as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts where description like '%love boards%' ORDER BY id DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('error');
```